# Can placing the Rails app in an SSD and running rails server in it damage the drive?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solid-state-drive

In a development environment, running `rails s` is a bit slow. I thought of moving my project files to the SSD. People say that we should not do too many writes and reads to an SSD. Will this damage the drive?

Comment: There seems to be a forming consensus that this either a) never really was a big problem, or b) that it isn't anymore. See [this](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9052925) article for example. Just in terms of read/write wear and tear, chances are your SSD will outlive the rest of your computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Practically, no.

> People say that we should not do too many writes and reads to an SSD.

These people are probably referring to doing orders of magnitude more disk I/O than starting a rails app does.